# Sql code convert into Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need to covert that sql code into ADO.net entity framework code please need some one help because i am new to the mvc asp.net .

Thnaks

```
SELECT A.cid, A.cname,    
B.sid, B.lname,B.fname,    
C.section,c.crn    
FROM courses A, students B, sections C, Registration D    
WHERE A.cid = C.cid AND    
B.sid = D.sid AND    
c.crn = d.crn AND    
c.crn = 1003 ;    
ORDER BY B.lname,B.fname ASC;
```

Comment: Where do you need help? We don't know where to start if you don't tell what you did so far. Have you got a context, for instance?

Comment: `private EmpiteHrSystemContextnew db = new EmpiteHrSystemContextnew();

        //
        // GET: /Employee/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

             

            var tblemployees = db.tblEmployees.Include(t => t.tblDepartment);
                                //.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName)
                                // .Select(y => new tblEmployee
                                // {

                                // }).ToList().OrderBy(y => y.FirstName);
            return View(tblemployees.ToList());
        }`

Comment: This is my Action result for index i need to return view with first asc in first name then asc in last name please help

Comment: Please edit this into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted in the comment you should do something like this to get the list ordered like you want.

```
var tblemployees = db.tblEmployees
                   .Include(t => t.tblDepartment)
                   .OrderBy(y => y.FirstName)
                   .ThenBy(x => x.LastName).ToList();
```